# what I need to do when change from ipv4 to ipv6

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, centos7, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have web server apache , nginx that running on centos , I want to change it to ipv6 .

I found the below url .

https://unix.stackexchange.com/quest...-on-centos-6-2

I just would like to confirm all thing that I need to do is just add/update the below to network config file ? no need to install any module for it ?

```
"
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=XXXX:C810:300100::3/56
IPV6_DEFAULTGW=XXXX:C810:300100::1
DNS3=2620:0:ccc::2
DNS4=2620:0:ccD::2 
"
```

Furthermore , I use apache , PHP , mysql , nginx etc , is there anything that I need to do ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

(i) To enable ipv6 in nginx, need to add only one line.

```
listen [::]:80;
```

80 is the port on which nginx is running.

(ii) For apache add listen directive as following in httpd.conf

```
Listen [ipv6 value]:80
```

For better understanding, please refer following link.
https://geekflare.com/enable-ipv6-nginx-apache/

Comment: For nginx , just add "listen [::]:80;" to config file regardless of the ipv6 value ?

Comment: Yes. By adding this configuration, nginx will support ipv6.